# <<MISSING VARIABLE " % s ">> while trying to parse the dictionary object that i passed from a context process

Tags: python, django, dictionary

i have a nav bar that should contain the category names and the sub category name. I created a file 'contextprocessor.py' and written the function to return the dictionary object.

```
# contextprocessor.py

def test_categories(request):
    return {'tests':categories}
```

I have written the dictionary in a separate file named 'category.py' and imported it in 'contextprocess.py'

```
# category.py

categories = [

        {
            "id": "1",
            "name":"Men",
            "url":"/men/",

         },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name":"WoMen",
            "url":"/women/",

         },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name":"Popular",
            "url":"/popular/",

         },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name":"New",
            "url":"/new/",

         },
]
```

my base.html looks like this

```
# base.html

{% for test in tests %}
      {{ test.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

when i run the page i get a

```
<< MISSING VARIABLE "test.name" >>
```

text on browser instead of the name of the categories.

Please help ! if i am not accessing the dictionary in a proper way...

Comment: try `return {'tests':categories[0] }`. To make your json result easier. If the `name` and `url` are ever going to bethe same, you might as well just remove the url key

Comment: the issue mostly lies in `contextprocessor.py` where you import the `categories`, try printing out the `type(categories)` and the logic used in importing the category file.

Comment: This is Jinja 2 or django templates? Django does not show errors in the browser for missing variable names in templates.

Comment: @JkShaw   .. hi ! it is type LIST.  can you help me now ? how do i access it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
{% for test in tests[tests] %}
      {{ test[name] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried the same but it says this error -->   " Could not parse the remainder: '[tests]' from 'tests[tests]' "